# Adding player head to Entity 1.11 minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For some reason, when I try to spawn a zombie with a player's head in `minecraft 1.11`, something glitches out and I just get a plain old zombie.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:NetherBolt}}]}
```

Is there a way to do it in `1.11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.11, you **must** have the `Count` tag with a value greater than 0. Otherwise the item is invalid and deleted as a result.

As well, the `Equipment` tag was replaced with `ArmorItems` and `HandItems` in 1.9.

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:NetherBolt}}]}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I looked everywhere and couldn't find anything.